# Drawing images?

Tags: php

I have a question with php. I wanna generate a signature based on some values and make them look something like this:

[image]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php
I think with it you can compose such an image out of several parts (e.g. the character face and the background) and add the text by adding text on top of it.